# How can I specify the start time and end time in PromQL?

Tags: curl, prometheus, promql

I want to subtract the `usage_num_objects` in a specfic time range, from `2023-04-01T17:00:00Z` to `2023-03-01T17:00:00Z`.

But I can't find anywhere about it syntax?

Here is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
curl -s $PROM_API -d 'query=delta({__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"})' -d start='2023-03-01T17:00:00Z' -d end='2023-04-01T17:00:00Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is cause by your query:

```
delta({__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"})
```

is not a valid query. Function [`delta`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta) accepts as argument range vector (in your case something like `{__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"}[1d]`)

You can change this, or to avoid hustle of counting difference in timestamps and converting it to Prometheus' format you can use something like this:

```
{__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"}@end() - {__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"}@start()
```

Pleasant bonus in this case: you result will be integer (if time series values are integer). It is not the case with delta.

Also, take a note, that usage of `=~` in selector `{__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"}` is redundant, as you did not supplied it with regex. Currently this selector is equivalent to `usage_num_objects{bucket="abc"}`

Demo of similar query [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=%7B__name__%3D%7E%22node_cpu_seconds_total%22%7D%40end()%20-%20%7B__name__%3D%7E%22node_cpu_seconds_total%22%7D%40start()&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1d&g0.end_input=2023-04-02%2006%3A00%3A00&g0.moment_input=2023-04-02%2006%3A00%3A00).

Command for query from the demo:

```bash
curl -s 'https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/api/v1/query_range' \
  -d 'query={__name__=~"node_cpu_seconds_total"}@end() - {__name__=~"node_cpu_seconds_total"}@start()' \
  -d 'start=2023-04-01T06:00:00Z' \
  -d end='2023-04-02T06:00:00Z' \
  -d step=1d
```

EDIT: For older versions, that don't support `@`:

```
{__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"} - {__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"} offset 30d
```

Also, if you need single value for every time series returned (instead of array) you could use endpoint `/api/v1/query`. For example:

```bash
curl -s 'https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/api/v1/query' \
  -d 'query={__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"} - {__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"} offset 30d' \
  -d time='2023-04-01T17:00:00Z'
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but seems like it cannot recognize "@end(). My command:

curl -s $PROM_API -d 'query={__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"}@end() - {__name__=~"usage_num_objects",bucket="abc"}@start()' -d start='2023-03-01T17:00:00Z' -d end='2023-04-01T17:00:00Z'

Comment: @huynp, your command is lacking of `step` parameter. I've edited my answer and added demo of similar query and command for it.

Comment: I just added the step parameter: -d start='2023-03-01T17:00:00Z' -d end='2023-04-01T17:00:00Z' -d step='30d' but the error still the same `for (time=1680592863565, step=2592000000): cannot recognize \"@end()`

Comment: @huynp, I believe `@` was introduced in 2.25.0. Could it be, that your version of Prometheus is older?

Comment: Thanks for your answers but actually, I need to specify a time range from `start` to `end`. Because some months have 31 days :-)

Comment: @huynp, it has nothing to do with this. Endpoint `/query` provides single value for every time series, while `/query_range` provides array (depends on timespan and steps, but at least 2 elements, I believe). And if you can't use `@ timestamp` you will **have to** calculate timespan (like `28d`, `30d`, `31d`) in your code independently before making request.